# How to prevent a deserialization error in Get operation

Tags: sap-cloud-sdk

We replicate data from Sales Cloud V2 system to our micro service and our services bases on java with the help of Get operation. Therefore we use the SAP Cloud SDK openAPI generator, which works fine.

In Sales Cloud V2 an account entity exist and for this entity we have an open API definition and with this we created the APIclient and model in our java application.

The account model has an attribute "web"and is defined as follow:

```
web string($uri)
maxLength: 1280
minLength: 1
title: Website
```

In the Sales Cloud V2 system exists an account with an attribute value of web with  "www.123.info" - with double quotation marks. This seems to be maintenance error in the system.

However, when we do a Get operation in order to fetch accounts from Sales Cloud V2 we get the following exception:

```
org.springframework.web.client.RestClientException: Error while extracting response for type [class com.sap.mkt.b2e.salescloudv2.model.Accountqueryresponse] and content type [application/json;charset=utf-8]; nested exception is org.springframework.http.converter.HttpMessageNotReadableException: JSON parse error: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.net.URI` from String ""www.123.info"": not a valid textual representation, problem: Illegal character in path at index 0: "www.123.info"; nested exception is com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.exc.InvalidFormatException: Cannot deserialize value of type `java.net.URI` from String ""www.123.info"": not a valid textual representation, problem: Illegal character in path at index 0: "www.123.info"
```

When I use Postman in order to fetch the data the reponse in Json looks like this:

```
...
   "correspondenceLanguage": "en",
   "eMail": "xy.z@sap.com",
   "web": "\"www.123.info\"",
   "id": "11ed932d-90e9-932e-afdb-81255ba8c000",
   "parentId": "11ed932d-90e9-1dfe-afdb-81255ba8c000",
...
```

The JSON response cannot be parsed and therefore the exception is raised.

Is there a way to include a validation check in order to prevent such an exception ? Or filter out not allowed char at the start of a string in order to make sure that value can be deserialized ?

Thanks a lot.

Best Regards,
Axel

Comment: Hi Axel, while I checkout possibilities to adapt the deserialization logic, can you have a look whether you can fix the root cause, namely the quoted String in the source system? Also, what do you mean exactly with validation check? Would you want to reject the payload in case of invalid data being sent (which the current exception basically already provides)?

Answer (score 0):

After discussing with my team and having a look at the code I see that there is no easy way to adapt the deserialization behavior from the client side.

But I would propose the following solution approaches:

1. Fix the data in the source system. From my understanding the problem is caused by the Sales Cloud V2 service returning data that is not correct according to the spec. Therefore, it's probably best to clean that up, so that also other system to stumble over it.
2. Adapt the OpenAPI spec you have to expect a String instead of a URI. Then you can implement the necessary cleanup (or rejection) in your code, without any Exceptions being thrown before.

Comment: Hi Christoph, thanks for your reply and recommendation. For attributes of type string the described parse issue does not occur. Meaning when I enter for account name (is of type String) a value like "Name123" in the source system (with double quotes) then this value can be deserialized and no exception is thrown while extracting response. So the workaround is to use type String instead of URI in our service.